# Nuxt.js App: Redeploy causes payload.js 404 Not found

Tags: vue.js, static, nuxt.js, http-status-code-404, progressive-web-apps

I have a webpage which runs a full static nuxt.js app. After a redeploy we sometimes experience some weird 404s, where payload.js was not found (404).

See the last two errors:

[image]

Could it be that some weird caching is causing this?
The problem appears (at least so far) only for users who visited the page, then a redeploy happendend, and after that they would see a failing page, because some js files were obviously missing...

I am very glad for any hints, why this could accur.

- Are there some specific nuxt caching settings, I could improve?
- Deploys are via netlify.com. But any caching there is disabled.
- I thought caching should no be a problem because of the build number in the file url...

Thanks a lot and cheers.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: not really. but it was not a big deal, because it had to do with the preloading of the routes displayed on the page. as soon as I navigated to the page the content would load again and fetch the correct payload.js.

The problem itself was caused because the redeploy woiuld make the payload.js available in another subfolder from another deploy. So when the page was still open the links would point to the wrong payload.js files.

As I said when navigating it was not a problem after all...

Comment: I'm actually facing the same issue - wondering if this should be an issue raised to nuxtjs?

Comment: Dec 2022 here , Nuxt 3 land ... same thing. Not a problem for users but i can't test the page on PageSPeed or test Rich Results for my client. The 404 header messes up the works